# PercentageFeatureSet() on several seurat objects

Tags: r, for-loop, seurat

I have many seurat objects created from count matrixes downloaded from GEO.
I want to use the PercentageFeatureSet() function on each of them to calculate the %MT.

I tried :

```
for (i in seu.list) {
  get(i)[["percent.mt"]] <- PercentageFeatureSet(get(i), pattern = "^MT-")
```

but got the following error:
Error in get(i) <- *vtmp* : could not find function "get<-"

How can I use PercentageFeatureSet() in loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably better to do this using `lapply`. Try this:

```r
seu.list <- lapply(seu.list, function(seuset) {
  seuset[["percent.mt"]] <- PercentageFeatureSet(seuset, pattern = "^MT-")
  seuset
})
```

Alternatively, if you really want to use a `for` loop:

```r
for (i in seq_len(length(seu.list))) {
  seu.list[[i]][["percent.mt"]] <- PercentageFeatureSet(seu.list[[i]], pattern = "^MT-") 
}
```

Comment: both lead to the same error: Error in UseMethod(generic = "DefaultAssay", object = object) : 
  no applicable method for 'DefaultAssay' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: How did you create `seu.list`?

Comment: It was just a chr vector or seurat object names. I now did a proper list by saving all my seurats objects and list it all using "seu.list <- lapply(seu.list, readRDS)". Both options now don't give errors but don't neither add the percent.mt feature

Comment: My mistake, it's working! I was looking in the wrong list sorry. Thanks!